# Why does Gson library show null value when debugging?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am parsing the Json and display on list view using gson library. When I insert my input stream I am getting null values. Can you please tell where I am wrong I will give you steps
I downloaded 2.3 Gson library. Then I make getter and setter

```
------------------

           package com.firstgroup.webservice;

        import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.Reader;

        import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
        import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
        import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
        import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
        import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

        import com.firstgroup.dto.Holder;
        import com.firstgroup.webservicecallback.WebserviceCallBack;
        import com.google.gson.Gson;

        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;

        public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
            private  WebserviceCallBack callBack;
            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progressDialog= new ProgressDialog((Context) callBack);
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
                progressDialog.setMessage("Webservice Call...");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                String responseString = null;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
    // I am getting correct result here ...
                        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Holder.class);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                        out.close();
                        responseString = out.toString();
                    } else{
                        //Closes the connection.
                        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    //TODO Handle problems..\
                    progressDialog.hide();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //TODO Handle problems..
                    progressDialog.hide();
                }
                return responseString;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //Do anything with response..
                if(callBack!=null){
                    callBack.getWebserviceResponse(result);
                }
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
            public void setObserver(WebserviceCallBack callback){
                callBack=callback;
            }


        }


        callback on main activity:

        @Override
        public void getWebserviceResponse(String response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("response", response);

            //can I used this code ?
// I want to used gson in main activity?
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Holder.class);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class:

```
public class Holder {
    List<deparaturedaseboarddto> data;
}
```

And change your below code:

```
deparaturedaseboarddto response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, deparaturedaseboarddto.class);
```

to:

```
Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Holder.class);
```

**Reason:** Your json text value has a root object named as `data` and it has a list of `deparaturedaseboarddto`. You are trying to deserialize this json value to a deparaturedaseboarddto instance but it is an object which has a list of `deparaturedaseboarddto`.

**Also (not relevant to your error);**

1) Class names starts with capital letters, and field names are camel case at Java.

2) You don't have to use `@SerializedName` if the java class's field name
    is same with the json value's field name.

3) Below mapping is probably prevent an error because there are no fields at json value named as `Result`. @SerializedName("Result") may be removed or replaced with @SerializedName("alertsId")

```
@SerializedName("Result")
int alertsId;
```

4) Also may want to replace below code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
out.close();
responseString = out.toString();
```

with:

```
responseString = gson.toJson(response1);
```

**Edit for the second question at the comment:**
If you want to use retrieve Holder instance from AsyncTask, make below edits.

Change this:

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

with this:

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Holder>
```

and:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... uri)
```

with this:

```
protected Holder doInBackground(String... uri)
```

and this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
```

with this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Holder result)
```

Comment: thanks i understand all bugs ,,..could u please tell why u take holder class.and i also got curret results also

Comment: @PallaviSharma I've tried to explain it at Reason part of the answer.

Comment: yes I understand little bit ..But is it neccessary to take the variable name data ? becuse I have jsonaarry of data

Comment: I haveone more Question ..I am sending the string a response using call back .can I do the same this using response string

Comment: You can rename the class name Holder to any name you want but the field inside this class must be named as data (or @SerializedName("data")) to make gson do its mapping. I couldn't understand the second question, sorry.

Comment: thanks for answer.please check my update..Actually I give also comment in code..Actually I am sending the response using callback to min activity..I want to do the holder/part in main activity

Comment: I've updated my answer but that is not a good thing to ask more than one question and answer them in same one. ıf my edit does not help you, please ask a new question.

Comment: could you please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519556/how-to-remove-fatal-exception-asynctask-in-android