# how to remove FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.getContent(BasicHttpEntity.java:84)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.writeTo(BasicHttpEntity.java:126)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:101)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.writeTo(BasicManagedEntity.java:126)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at com.firstgroup.webservice.RequestTask.doInBackground(RequestTask.java:51)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at com.firstgroup.webservice.RequestTask.doInBackground(RequestTask.java:1)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-23 00:41:00.705: E/AndroidRuntime(3622):     ... 4 more
```

Hi

I am calling my web service using gson library I am getting exception.I don't know why it is occur .could you please tell me removing this error
I will give you steps what I did ..
1 )`Main activity`

```
public class Appliacationload extends Activity implements WebserviceCallBack{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.appliacationload);

        /*WebserviceMethod callDepartudeDashboard=new WebserviceMethod();
        callDepartudeDashboard.setObserver(this);
        callDepartudeDashboard.getwebService(ConstantVariable.dashboardWebServiceURL+"a/"+"arrival"+"?crsCode=hnh");*/
        RequestTask callWebService=new RequestTask();
        callWebService.setObserver(this);
         callWebService.execute(ConstantVariable.dashboardWebServiceURL+"a/"+"arrival"+"?crsCode=vic");



    }

    @Override
    public void getWebserviceResponse(String response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("response", response);



    }

}
```

and I have one holder and RequestTask class to call webservice and return call back .

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    private  WebserviceCallBack callBack;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog= new ProgressDialog((Context) callBack);
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Webservice Call...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Holder.class);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..\
            progressDialog.hide();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
        if(callBack!=null){
            callBack.getWebserviceResponse(result);
        }
        progressDialog.hide();
    }
    public void setObserver(WebserviceCallBack callback){
        callBack=callback;
    }


}
```

Holder class;

```
public class Holder {
    List<deparaturedaseboarddto> data;
}
```

**New Update** when I change my request task like that ..

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream>{
    private  WebserviceCallBack callBack;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog= new ProgressDialog((Context) callBack);
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Webservice Call...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                /*Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Holder.class);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();*/
                return response.getEntity().getContent();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..\
            progressDialog.hide();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..

        if(callBack!=null){
            callBack.getWebserviceResponse(result);
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog=null;

    }
    public void setObserver(WebserviceCallBack callback){
        callBack=callback;
    }


}
```

and **call back** like that

```
public interface WebserviceCallBack {
    public void getWebserviceResponse(InputStream result);

}
```

and **main activity** like that

```
public class Appliacationload extends Activity implements WebserviceCallBack{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.appliacationload);

        /*WebserviceMethod callDepartudeDashboard=new WebserviceMethod();
        callDepartudeDashboard.setObserver(this);
        callDepartudeDashboard.getwebService(ConstantVariable.dashboardWebServiceURL+"a/"+"arrival"+"?crsCode=hnh");*/
        RequestTask callWebService=new RequestTask();
          callWebService.setObserver(this);
         callWebService.execute(ConstantVariable.dashboardWebServiceURL+"a/"+"arrival"+"?crsCode=vic");



    }

    @Override
    public void getWebserviceResponse(InputStream result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(result);
      Gson gson = new Gson();
    Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Holder.class);
    Log.d("-----", "naveen");
    }
```

I got this exception why ..?I am sending the input stream on call back and make here in main activity ..

exception:

```
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:161)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1298)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1028)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:796)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:178)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:183)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:743)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.firstgroup.applicationload.Appliacationload.getWebserviceResponse(Appliacationload.java:48)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.firstgroup.webservice.RequestTask.onPostExecute(RequestTask.java:77)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.firstgroup.webservice.RequestTask.onPostExecute(RequestTask.java:1)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-23 03:07:33.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22412):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you can only consume `Content` from `Entity` once.

You did it twice (maybe without you knowing it) in here

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
```

and here

```
response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
```

I know this is sounds  a little weird but actually the writeTo() function will get content from the entity to write to the `OutputStream`. You can see it in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#writeTo(java.io.OutputStream))

Another workaround you can use is turning it to string and let GSON handle it

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    String responseString = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); // content will be consume only once
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(responseString, Holder.class);
        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..\
        progressDialog.hide();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
        progressDialog.hide();
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

I hope my answer can help you!

Comment: I got the what you want to say..could you please elaborate more

Comment: do you have you gmail Id ...please I will show My code..it is small code but have this issue

Comment: that correct I got it But I have few problem I change My some code .then expection come again..check my update in 2 min

Comment: @PallaviSharma maybe you need to open a new question :)

Comment: I will create new one if you check update if you able to solve please udate anwser..thanks