# how to remove back button exception when back button press in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am getting this exception when I press back button of simulator.could you please tell which type of this error is this .how to resolve this error

```
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185): Activity com.firstgroup.applicationload.Appliacationload has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d25790 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-729,324} that was originally added here
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.firstgroup.applicationload.Appliacationload has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d25790 G.E..... R.....ID 0,0-729,324} that was originally added here
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at com.firstgroup.webservice.RequestTask.onPreExecute(RequestTask.java:36)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at com.firstgroup.applicationload.Appliacationload.onCreate(Appliacationload.java:37)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-23 01:22:37.435: E/WindowManager(9185):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my main activity

```
package com.firstgroup.applicationload;


public class Appliacationload extends Activity implements WebserviceCallBack{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.appliacationload);


        RequestTask callWebService=new RequestTask();
          callWebService.setObserver(this);
         callWebService.execute(ConstantVariable.dashboardWebServiceURL+"a/"+"arrival"+"?crsCode=vic");



    }

@Override
public void getWebserviceResponse(InputStream response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}
```

}

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream>{
    private  WebserviceCallBack callBack;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressDialog= new ProgressDialog((Context) callBack);
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Webservice Call...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                /*Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Holder response1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Holder.class);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();*/
                return response.getEntity().getContent();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..\
            progressDialog.hide();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
        progressDialog.hide();
        progressDialog=null;
        if(callBack!=null){
            callBack.getWebserviceResponse(result);
        }

    }
    public void setObserver(WebserviceCallBack callback){
        callBack=callback;
    }


}
```

json observer :

```
  public interface WebserviceCallBack {
        public void getWebserviceResponse(InputStream result);

    }
I just
```

call web service .I got the response on my call back but when i press back it crash why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Using ProgressDialog.hide() only hides it from the screen and does not remove it,
meaning the dialog still exists in the window only that it is not visible.

When your Activity finishes, i.e. when the back button is pressed, you need to remove any dialog yourself. So just make sure to call ProgressDialog.dismiss() when you are exiting your Activity.

---

In short, you are trying to display a dialog in your Activity which no longer exists or has window focus.

I can see you are trying to run RequestTask, and I can guess that in its onPreExecute method  there is a ProgressDialog that you want to show.

You have a few options to avoid this problem, depending what you want to do:

1. If you really need to launch this task even when your Activity does not have focus,
   you can simply remove anything that touches the UI thread in the AsyncTask's onPreExecute, onProgressUpdate, and onPostExecute. The task will then silently run in the background.
2. Similar to the previous option, you can create a Service to do the work in the background.
3. Lastly, you can also choose not to launch the task if your Activity is paused.

Comment: wait i will update you.still getting the same error I will update my Question with code.

Comment: Try changing all progressDialog.hide() to progressDialog.dismiss().

Comment: correct answer..thanks for help man…we are also face one more problem .can you please tell this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519556/how-to-remove-fatal-exception-asynctask-in-android